# Searching a set of unique pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, set, unique-ptr

I have a set of unique pointers pointing to objects. Occasionally, I will reveal some of the raw pointers to these objects so other parts of the code can do stuff with the objects. This code does not know whether the pointers are pointing to objects maintained by a certain set of unique pointers or not, so I need to check whether the object pointed to by a pointer is in a unique pointer set.

In simple code:

```
int* x = new int(42);
std::set<std::unique_ptr<int>> numbers;
numbers.insert(std::unique_ptr<int>(x));

numbers.find(x) // does not compile
```

I understand why the code does not compile, but I cannot think of a way to search for the element with the STL. Is there anything that caters to my needs or will I have to iterate over all elements of the set manually?

Comment: You could instead use a `std::map<int *, std::unique_ptr<int>>` ...

Comment: What about `numbers.find(std::unique_ptr<int>(x))`? I think, creating the temporary `unique_ptr` object is the only option, if you want to stick to a `set<unique_ptr<int>>`.

Comment: @PhilippMatthiasSchäfer: That would be creating a unique_ptr to an object that may already be owned by a `unique_ptr`. And therefore is bad, leading to a double-delete. And if it isn't owned by a `unique_ptr`, it is now, so it may still break unless you `release` it.

Comment: I think creating a second `unique_ptr` pointing to the same memory location is not a good idea. That temporary `unique_ptr` will be destroyed after `find` has returned and take the allocated memory with it, leaving a `unique_ptr` in the set referencing unallocated memory.

Comment: It should be noted that C++14 will be removing this particular limitation; it will add `find` overloads that take an arbitrary type which the `Compare` function can compare with the key type.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh, nice! I was born too soon...

Comment: You could set up a custom deleter with a flag whether or not to delete when it goes out of scope, and feed that to the `.find` function. It's hacky, but I think it'd work.

Comment: Why aren't you using shared_ptrs?

Comment: Because the relationship described by the `unique_ptr`s is a composition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `std::find_if` like this:
`std::find_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<int>& p) { return p.get() == x;});`

Comment: This would lose all of the efficiency of a `set`, as it would be a linear access.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, but I don't see any other way than doing it in linear time.

Comment: Doesn't find_if basically do the same thing as `for(it = set.begin(); it != set.end(); ++it) { if(*it == searching) return; }`? This would be equal in execution time to manual iteration, right?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, instead of coding the loop yourself you will be using the `find_if`. No benefits in terms of performance.

Comment: @Asha I think Nicol's point is more about the fact that the usual `std::set<>::find()` does it in sub-linear time. And that's true...

Comment: Yes, but that is because `set` uses some sort of internal ordering. But I'm afraid there is no way to find out the `unique_ptr`'s key/position in the set only by knowing its value.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [boost::ptr_set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_set.html) instead?